# If condition to add link magento?

Tags: xml, magento

My xml code:

```
<customer_account>
    <reference name="example_link">
        <action method="addLink" module="example" ifconfig="example/general/enable"><name>my_review</name><path>example/account/list/</path><label>My Review</label></action>
    </reference>
</customer_account>
```

I am creating new navigation in customer account now i want to add one link in that navigation but i want to check that customer is approve as seller or not if its not approve than i dont want to add link in that navigation how can i do this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a block inside the customer_account_navigation and in that block, add the link to the parent block if your conditions are satisfied.

So in your layout goes this:

```
<customer_account>
    <reference name="example_link">
        <block type="[module]/customer_link" as="[module]_customer_link" name="[module]_customer_link">
            <action method="addLinkToParentBlock" />
        </block>
    </reference>
</customer_account>
```

And your block class shoud look like this:

```
class [Namespace]_[Module]_Block_Customer_Link extends Mage_Core_Block_Abstract 
{
    public function addLinkToParentBlock() 
    {
        $parent = $this->getParentBlock();
        if ($parent) {
            if (your condition goes here) {
                $parent->addLink(
                    'Label goes here',
                    'Url goes here',
                    'title goes here',
                );

            }
        } 
    }
}
```

This way, your block will get instantiated. It will have no output, but the method `addLinkToParentBlock` will be called.

Reference Marius Answer:https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/42547/18722

Comment: great approach! but can i modify the order of the custom link? i want it to be placed before a specific link in parent

Answer (score 2):

use handler and update by observer.. 
event will be

```
   <controller_action_layout_load_before>
                <observers>
                    <add_link_indashboard>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>seller/observer</class>
                        <method>addCustomLink</method>
                    </add_link_indashboard>
                </observers>
            </controller_action_layout_load_before>
```

and than in observer method

```
public function addCustomLink(Varien_Event_Observer $observer){

        if(Check customer condition ){        
                     Mage::app()->getLayout()->getUpdate()->addHandle('customer_link');        
        } 

    }
```

and define the link in your xml